Correct way of using cross-correlation to find time difference between 2 sine waves
I'm not a software engineer nor a hardware engineer, but I've been trying to learn some signal processing algorithms to apply to my project.
I want to use cross-correlation to find time difference between 2 signals. But any attempts I made using Python or C# didn't give me correct result. I'm almost 100% sure I'm missing some obvious things. There must be a trap for a young player like me.
I turned to ChatGPT and copilot and they didn't give me the correct solution, and then finally came here to seek your help. Please help me. I've been struggling this for 2 weeks now.
This Python code iterates phase angle difference from 0 to 360 degrees, but it gives wrong cross-correlation coefficients and thus giving wrong phase difference results.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import correlate

def generate_signal(frequency, amplitude, phase_angle, num_samples, sampling_rate):
    phase_radians = np.pi * phase_angle / 180.0
    time = np.arange(num_samples) / sampling_rate
    signal = amplitude * np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * frequency * time + phase_radians)
    return signal

def find_phase_difference(signal1, signal2, sampling_rate, frequency):
    n = len(signal1)
    ccf = correlate(signal2, signal1, mode='full')  # Changed order here
    lags = np.arange(-n + 1, n)
    max_corr_index = np.argmax(ccf)
    lag = lags[max_corr_index]
    time_shift = lag / sampling_rate
    max_correlation = ccf[max_corr_index] / (np.std(signal1) * np.std(signal2) * n)
    
    # Convert time shift to phase shift in degrees
    phase_shift = (time_shift * frequency * 360) % 360
    if phase_shift > 180:
        phase_shift -= 360  # Adjust phase shift to range [-180, 180]
    elif phase_shift < -180:
        phase_shift += 360  # Adjust phase shift to range [-180, 180]

    return max_correlation, time_shift, phase_shift

# Parameters
frequency = 5  # Frequency in Hz
amplitude = 1.0  # Amplitude of the signal
sampling_rate = 1000  # Sampling rate in Hz
num_samples = 1000  # Number of samples

angles = np.arange(0, 361)  # Angles from 0 to 360 degrees
results = []

for angle in angles:
    signal1 = generate_signal(frequency, amplitude, 0, num_samples, sampling_rate)
    signal2 = generate_signal(frequency, amplitude, angle, num_samples, sampling_rate)
    
    max_corr, time_shift, phase_shift = find_phase_difference(signal1, signal2, sampling_rate, frequency)
    results.append((angle, max_corr, time_shift, phase_shift))

for angle, max_corr, time_shift, phase_shift in results:
    print(f"Angle: {angle} degrees, Max Correlation: {max_corr:.6f}, Time Shift: {time_shift:.10f} seconds, Phase Shift: {phase_shift:.6f} degrees")

# Plot the results for better visualization
angles, max_corrs, time_shifts, phase_shifts = zip(*results)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))

plt.subplot(3, 1, 1)
plt.plot(angles, max_corrs, label="Max Correlation")
plt.xlabel("Angle (degrees)")
plt.ylabel("Max Correlation")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3, 1, 2)
plt.plot(angles, time_shifts, label="Time Shift")
plt.xlabel("Angle (degrees)")
plt.ylabel("Time Shift (seconds)")
plt.legend()

plt.subplot(3, 1, 3)
plt.plot(angles, phase_shifts, label="Phase Shift")
plt.xlabel("Angle (degrees)")
plt.ylabel("Phase Shift (degrees)")
plt.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

The results are as below;
Angle: 0 degrees, Max Correlation: 1.000000, Time Shift: 0.0000000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 0.000000 degrees
Angle: 1 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999903, Time Shift: -0.0010000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -1.800000 degrees
Angle: 2 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999994, Time Shift: -0.0010000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -1.800000 degrees
Angle: 3 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999944, Time Shift: -0.0020000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -3.600000 degrees
Angle: 4 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999973, Time Shift: -0.0020000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -3.600000 degrees
Angle: 5 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999967, Time Shift: -0.0030000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -5.400000 degrees
Angle: 6 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999933, Time Shift: -0.0030000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -5.400000 degrees
Angle: 7 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999968, Time Shift: -0.0040000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -7.200000 degrees
Angle: 8 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999870, Time Shift: -0.0040000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -7.200000 degrees
Angle: 9 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999941, Time Shift: -0.0050000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -9.000000 degrees
Angle: 10 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999808, Time Shift: -0.0060000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -10.800000 degrees
Angle: 11 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999883, Time Shift: -0.0060000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -10.800000 degrees
Angle: 12 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999781, Time Shift: -0.0070000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -12.600000 degrees
Angle: 13 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999788, Time Shift: -0.0070000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -12.600000 degrees
Angle: 14 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999714, Time Shift: -0.0080000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -14.400000 degrees
Angle: 15 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999654, Time Shift: -0.0080000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -14.400000 degrees
Angle: 16 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999605, Time Shift: -0.0090000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -16.200000 degrees
Angle: 17 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999475, Time Shift: -0.0090000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -16.200000 degrees
Angle: 18 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999447, Time Shift: -0.0100000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -18.000000 degrees
Angle: 19 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999247, Time Shift: -0.0100000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -18.000000 degrees
Angle: 20 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999239, Time Shift: -0.0110000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -19.800000 degrees
Angle: 21 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999014, Time Shift: -0.0120000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -21.600000 degrees
Angle: 22 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.998975, Time Shift: -0.0120000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -21.600000 degrees
Angle: 23 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.998764, Time Shift: -0.0130000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -23.400000 degrees
Angle: 24 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.998652, Time Shift: -0.0130000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -23.400000 degrees
Angle: 25 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.998453, Time Shift: -0.0140000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -25.200000 degrees
Angle: 26 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.998268, Time Shift: -0.0140000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -25.200000 degrees
Angle: 27 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.998078, Time Shift: -0.0150000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -27.000000 degrees
Angle: 28 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.997818, Time Shift: -0.0150000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -27.000000 degrees
Angle: 29 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.997635, Time Shift: -0.0160000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -28.800000 degrees
Angle: 30 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.997301, Time Shift: -0.0160000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -28.800000 degrees
Angle: 31 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.997123, Time Shift: -0.0170000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -30.600000 degrees
Angle: 32 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.996719, Time Shift: -0.0180000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -32.400000 degrees
Angle: 33 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.996538, Time Shift: -0.0180000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -32.400000 degrees
Angle: 34 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.996136, Time Shift: -0.0190000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -34.200000 degrees
...
Angle: 60 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.981387, Time Shift: -0.0330000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -59.400000 degrees
Angle: 61 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.980654, Time Shift: -0.0330000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -59.400000 degrees
Angle: 62 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.979771, Time Shift: -0.0340000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -61.200000 degrees
Angle: 63 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.978963, Time Shift: -0.0340000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -61.200000 degrees
Angle: 64 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.978083, Time Shift: -0.0350000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -63.000000 degrees
Angle: 65 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.977202, Time Shift: -0.0350000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -63.000000 degrees
Angle: 66 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.976326, Time Shift: -0.0360000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -64.800000 degrees
Angle: 67 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.975372, Time Shift: -0.0360000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -64.800000 degrees
Angle: 68 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.974503, Time Shift: -0.0370000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -66.600000 degrees
Angle: 69 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.973478, Time Shift: -0.0370000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -66.600000 degrees
Angle: 70 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.972618, Time Shift: -0.0380000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -68.400000 degrees
Angle: 71 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.971543, Time Shift: -0.0390000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -70.200000 degrees
Angle: 72 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.970672, Time Shift: -0.0390000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -70.200000 degrees
Angle: 73 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.969611, Time Shift: -0.0400000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -72.000000 degrees
Angle: 74 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.968671, Time Shift: -0.0400000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -72.000000 degrees
Angle: 75 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.967626, Time Shift: -0.0410000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -73.800000 degrees
Angle: 76 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.966617, Time Shift: -0.0410000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -73.800000 degrees
Angle: 77 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.965591, Time Shift: -0.0420000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -75.600000 degrees
Angle: 78 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.964515, Time Shift: -0.0420000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -75.600000 degrees
Angle: 79 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.963510, Time Shift: -0.0430000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -77.400000 degrees
Angle: 80 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.962368, Time Shift: -0.0430000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -77.400000 degrees
Angle: 81 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.961388, Time Shift: -0.0440000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -79.200000 degrees
Angle: 82 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.960207, Time Shift: -0.0450000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -81.000000 degrees
Angle: 83 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.959229, Time Shift: -0.0450000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -81.000000 degrees
Angle: 84 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.958077, Time Shift: -0.0460000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -82.800000 degrees
Angle: 85 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.957037, Time Shift: -0.0460000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -82.800000 degrees
Angle: 86 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.955918, Time Shift: -0.0470000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -84.600000 degrees
Angle: 87 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.954816, Time Shift: -0.0470000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -84.600000 degrees
Angle: 88 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.953735, Time Shift: -0.0480000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -86.400000 degrees
Angle: 89 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.952572, Time Shift: -0.0480000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -86.400000 degrees
Angle: 90 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.951530, Time Shift: -0.0490000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -88.200000 degrees
Angle: 91 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.950309, Time Shift: -0.0490000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -88.200000 degrees
Angle: 92 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.949310, Time Shift: -0.0500000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -90.000000 degrees
Angle: 93 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.948125, Time Shift: -0.0510000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -91.800000 degrees
Angle: 94 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.947079, Time Shift: -0.0510000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -91.800000 degrees
Angle: 95 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.945943, Time Shift: -0.0520000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -93.600000 degrees
Angle: 96 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.944841, Time Shift: -0.0520000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -93.600000 degrees
Angle: 97 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.943758, Time Shift: -0.0530000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -95.400000 degrees
Angle: 98 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.942602, Time Shift: -0.0530000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -95.400000 degrees
Angle: 99 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.941575, Time Shift: -0.0540000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -97.200000 degrees
Angle: 100 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.940371, Time Shift: -0.0550000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -99.000000 degrees
Angle: 101 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.939397, Time Shift: -0.0550000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -99.000000 degrees
Angle: 102 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.938255, Time Shift: -0.0560000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -100.800000 degrees
Angle: 103 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.937230, Time Shift: -0.0560000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -100.800000 degrees
Angle: 104 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.936153, Time Shift: -0.0570000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -102.600000 degrees
Angle: 105 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.935078, Time Shift: -0.0570000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -102.600000 degrees
Angle: 106 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.934068, Time Shift: -0.0580000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -104.400000 degrees
Angle: 107 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.932945, Time Shift: -0.0580000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -104.400000 degrees
Angle: 108 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.932006, Time Shift: -0.0590000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -106.200000 degrees
Angle: 109 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.930903, Time Shift: -0.0600000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -108.000000 degrees
Angle: 110 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.929970, Time Shift: -0.0600000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -108.000000 degrees
Angle: 111 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.928943, Time Shift: -0.0610000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -109.800000 degrees
...
Angle: 165 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900371, Time Shift: -0.0920000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -165.600000 degrees
Angle: 166 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900360, Time Shift: -0.0920000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -165.600000 degrees
Angle: 167 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900263, Time Shift: -0.0930000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -167.400000 degrees
Angle: 168 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900206, Time Shift: -0.0930000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -167.400000 degrees
Angle: 169 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900177, Time Shift: -0.0940000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -169.200000 degrees
Angle: 170 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900072, Time Shift: -0.0940000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -169.200000 degrees
Angle: 171 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900108, Time Shift: -0.0950000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -171.000000 degrees
Angle: 172 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899980, Time Shift: -0.0960000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -172.800000 degrees
Angle: 173 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900051, Time Shift: -0.0960000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -172.800000 degrees
Angle: 174 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899982, Time Shift: -0.0970000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -174.600000 degrees
Angle: 175 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900003, Time Shift: -0.0970000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -174.600000 degrees
Angle: 176 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899989, Time Shift: -0.0980000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -176.400000 degrees
Angle: 177 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899959, Time Shift: -0.0980000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -176.400000 degrees
Angle: 178 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899997, Time Shift: -0.0990000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -178.200000 degrees
Angle: 179 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899913, Time Shift: -0.0990000000 seconds, Phase Shift: -178.200000 degrees
Angle: 180 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900000, Time Shift: -0.1000000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 180.000000 degrees
Angle: 181 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899912, Time Shift: -0.1010000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 178.200000 degrees
Angle: 182 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899995, Time Shift: -0.1010000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 178.200000 degrees
Angle: 183 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899952, Time Shift: 0.0980000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 176.400000 degrees
Angle: 184 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899980, Time Shift: 0.0980000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 176.400000 degrees
Angle: 185 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899987, Time Shift: 0.0970000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 174.600000 degrees
Angle: 186 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899962, Time Shift: 0.0970000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 174.600000 degrees
Angle: 187 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900021, Time Shift: 0.0960000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 172.800000 degrees
Angle: 188 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.899945, Time Shift: 0.0960000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 172.800000 degrees
Angle: 189 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.900059, Time Shift: 0.0950000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 171.000000 degrees
...
Angle: 255 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.933193, Time Shift: 0.0570000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 102.600000 degrees
Angle: 256 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.934259, Time Shift: 0.0570000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 102.600000 degrees
Angle: 257 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.935316, Time Shift: 0.0560000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 100.800000 degrees
Angle: 258 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.936333, Time Shift: 0.0560000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 100.800000 degrees

Angle: 318 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.992142, Time Shift: 0.0230000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 41.400000 degrees
Angle: 319 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.992598, Time Shift: 0.0220000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 39.600000 degrees
degrees
Angle: 358 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999992, Time Shift: 0.0010000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 1.800000 degrees
Angle: 359 degrees, Max Correlation: 0.999901, Time Shift: 0.0010000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 1.800000 degrees
Angle: 360 degrees, Max Correlation: 1.000000, Time Shift: 0.0000000000 seconds, Phase Shift: 0.000000 degrees

I tried to find correct answer using Excel Spreadsheet, Python code and C# code and also sought help with ChatGPT and Copilot. None give me the answer.

It sounds like the actual problem here is with understanding the math that needs to be implemented, rather than with actually writing code. Please read How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?, and first consider if you can ask (or better yet, find) a useful question on [math.se] to clarify the actual requirement. If you actually know what needs to be implemented that isn't working, please start by clearly stating the calculation that needs to be done, and producing a proper specification or [mre] as appropriate.

Karl. Vielen Dank. I just found out what was wrong. I didn't know how to draw the sine wave. Instead of drawing graph with phase angle, I should have shifted the complete cycle of the sine wave back and forth by the space designated by the phase angle. Only that way can I get the correct x-corr result. Have a good day!
